# Communicate from one page to another? JavaScript, PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm building a prototype where on one page A I have a controller. Imagine a TV remote. On another page B, independent of form A -- it can be a different screen/computer -- with some elements X, Y, and Z that are going to be animated by the remote on page A.

My first idea would be:

- Remote on page A saves an action wanted and sends JSON.
- I create a listener on page B that reads the JSON to listen to what action to trigger.

I wonder if this the right direction.

It is just for a prototype so it doesn't have to be a production-perfect idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [web sockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) for this.

Comment: @Francesco node.js is awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you're using 2 computers, both pointed at the website, as this technique could work in both scenarios.

If it's just a prototype, you could just simply have your page B poll the server every 5 seconds to look for updates that were submitted by page A.

However, in reality, for a production app with thousands of users, this could consume lots of bandwidth and put a heavy load on your server. To compensate for the load and bandwidth usage, you could increase the polling rate to 10 seconds, or 30 seconds, but in response to this change your users would experience delays while they wait for the browser to request an update from the server.

In a production app, many developers are turning to Comet as a solution. Comet is basically a term given by Alex Russell for a technique that involves using the request/response cycle to simulate server-push.

The general idea is that the browser makes a request to the server, and the server holds that connection open indefinitely. The connection remains open until another user posts an update to the server, in which case, the server then sends a response to the connected users.

The Dojo and Jetty team have demonstrations where they show that this technique can scale to 20,000 connections, when using continuations.

While I think you can carry out your experiment just fine with a database and/or some session variables, if your want to learn more about Comet on PHP, check out [How to Implement Comet with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start). Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

I also wanted to say that you *definitely* have the right idea for how to conceptually think about your message passing with JSON:

> - I create a listener on page B that reads the JSON to listen to what action to trigger.

I really like how you are thinking about passing a *message* that then tells the page what action to trigger. If you think about it, you could reuse your message passing concept to call other commands so that you avoid reinventing the wheel when a new command comes along that you need to call. Regardless of whether you poll, use Comet, or use WebSockets, it's a great idea to think about abstractions and generic, reusable data transports.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this either with polling (having page B constantly poll for updates from the server) or use a server push technology like server sent events or websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would work.  You could also just make it the same way you would make a vector line animation.  Send the "commands" for movement to a server and record them (in a database, file, whatever) the client program can then request and redraw the movement smoothly any time and anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cron job to execute Page B for every x unit time will make you check for any latest updated json (queried/returned output according your logic) from Page A. This way, you can use new updated json from page A and do your further task...